# angular 5 State management using Redux and Behavior Subject

Tags: angular5, angular6, state-management

How do you do state management in angular 5 ? Between Redux and Behavior Subject which approach is better to follow and why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Service Layers: Redux, RxJs and Ngrx Store - When to Use a Store And Why?](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/)

**ngrx sample example**

Install the below packages:

- npm install @ngrx/store --save
- npm install @ngrx/effects --save
- app.module.ts

---

```
import { appReducer } from './state/app.reducer';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...

    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './state/app.state';
import { SetAppTitleAction, getAppTitle } from './state/app-title';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
    `<h1>{{appTitle$ | async}}</h1>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  appTitle$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.appTitle$ = this.store.select(getAppTitle);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetAppTitleAction('Location: AppComponent'));
  }
}
```

**app-title.action.ts**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const SetAppTitle = 'Set App Title';

export class SetAppTitleAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SetAppTitle;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type AppTitleActions = SetAppTitleAction;
```

**app-title.reducer.ts**

```
import { AppTitleActions, SetAppTitle } from './app-title.actions';

export function appTitleReducer(state: string, action: AppTitleActions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SetAppTitle:
      return action.payload;
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './app-title.actions';
import { AppState } from './app.state';

export const getState = (state: AppState) => state;
export const getAppTitle = createSelector(getState, state => state.appTitle);
```

**app.reducer.ts**

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
import { appTitleReducer } from './app-title/app-title.reducer';
import { versionInfoReducer } from './version-info/version-info.reducer';

export const appReducer: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    appTitle: appTitleReducer
};


export interface AppState {
    appTitle: string;
}
```